# How to have a text input with curved text in js/react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, svg, textinput

I want a one line text input field with curved text in my React Native app. I know how to build curved text using SVG, but this is a text outside a text input field. I could use a hidden text input to trigger the keyboard and then write text, but I would loose the functionalities of a text input field (i.e. cursor, subtext selection etc.).

Is it possible to curve the text of a text input field somehow?